# Swift "Backslash" how to use it

Tags: ios, swift

There are some code:

```
let noteNamesWithSharps = ["C", "C♯", "D", "D♯", "E", "F", "F♯", "G", "G♯", "A", "A♯", "B"]

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(noteNamesWithSharps.count)))

lhsinterval.text = "Backslash(noteNamesWithSharps[randomIndex])"
```

i am a beginner to learn swift, Backslash in swift is use for what?

Comment: Did you write "Backslash" literally, or is your question about the `"\"` character? – Anyway, you don't need it here at all, just `lhsinterval.text = noteNamesWithSharps[randomIndex]` would work.

Comment: yes is "\", so what is it used for, because when i use label to print text, it is error , example it cant print float type in label text, but when i add backslash it is work. thanks

Comment: Open "The Swift Programming Language" in iBooks, search for "backslash". The first hit explains it.

Comment: If you are learning a new programming language, then the first places you should look for answers are: 1) the online documentation for the language on its website, 2) an online tutorial, 3) a text book, 4) Google search, 5) StackOverflow **search**.  (This is what is meant by "doing your research" ... before asking a question.)

Answer (score 3):

In Swift (talking about Strings in your case), you would use the backslash when aiming to construct a new string value based on other constants, variables, literals, or expressions by including their values inside a your string; That's what called [*String Interpolation*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292).

So in your case, implementing:

```
lhsinterval.text = "\(noteNamesWithSharps[randomIndex])"
```

would add the -Integer- value of `noteNamesWithSharps[randomIndex]` into a String and set it to the `lhsinterval.text`.

**Quick Example**:

if you have some variables as numbers and you want to add them into a string, you could do it like this:

```
let name = "John"
let age = 20
let weight = 74
let height = 166

let myString = "Hello I'm \(name), I'm \(age) years old\nMy weight is: \(weight) Kg\t My height: \(height) cm"
print(myString)

/* Output:

 Hello I'm John, I'm 20 years old
 My weight is: 74 Kg     My height: 166 cm

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**backSlash "\" when used with parenthesis**, is used to incorporate the value of variable/constant into a String, and the process is known as **String InterPolation**.

For example:

```
let aValue = 20
print("the value is \(aValue)") // output: the value is 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
lhsinterval.text = "\(noteNamesWithSharps[randomIndex])"
```